# .NET MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes isnt working for class's properties!

Tags: .net, serialization

I have created a custom attribute & used it in properties (not fields) of my class.

When i call FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers, it does give me all the properties

But when i try to read the attribute using MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes, it doesnt give me any value.

When i try to achieve the same using object.GetType().GetProperties().GetCustomAttributes, It works perfectly.

Any idea why it is not giving the information in MemberInfo?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute { }

//DOES NOT WORK
MemberInfo[] members = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(recordObject.GetType());
object[] attributes = members[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false)

//WORKS
PropertyInfo[] properties = recordObject.GetType().GetProperties();
object[] attributes = properties[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false);
```

Comment: Could you construct a short but complete example of this that demonstrates the problem, and add it to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers` does not return any properties but rather fields of the serializable class.

So for instance of the following sample class:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class TestClass
    {
        private int _test;

        [MyAttribute]
        public int Test
        {
            get { return _test; }
            set { _test = value; }
        }
    }
```

`FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers` with get use `MemberInfo` of `_test` field, but GetType().GetProperties() with return `MemberInfo` of the property.

And because the field itself doesn't have any attributes attached to it therefore `GetCustomAttributes` won't return anything.

Comment: i very much agree with you, but it is little weird from .net that you cant read attributes of properties this way.

Comment: @Sharjeel Ahmed, from some point, yes; but put it another way: using `FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers` you don't actually get any properties to read attributes of.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the first member returned in

```
FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(recordObject.GetType());
```

is not actually the property you expected.